# why does filter remove null value by default on spark dataframe?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql

`filter` on basic scala collections containing `null` values has the following (and quite intuitive) behaviour:

```
scala> List("a", "b", null).filter(_ != "a")
res0: List[String] = List(b, null)
```

However, I was very surprised to figure out that the following filter removes nulls in spark dataframe:

```
scala> val df = List(("a", null), ( "c", "d")).toDF("A", "B")
scala> df.show
+---+----+
|  A|   B|
+---+----+
|  a|null|
|  c|   d|
+---+----+
scala> df.filter('B =!= "d").show
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
+---+---+
```

If I want to keep `null` values, I should add

```
df.filter('B =!= "d" || 'B.isNull).show
+---+----+
|  A|   B|
+---+----+
|  a|null|
+---+----+
```

Personally, I think that removing nulls by default is very error prone. 
Why this choice? and why is not explicitely stated in the api documentation? Am I missing something?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131942/spark-join-produces-wrong-results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the standard for SQL is not to be null-safe - so Spark SQL follows this (but not Scala).

Spark dataframes has a null-safe equality though

```
scala> df.filter($"B" <=> null).show
+---+----+
|  A|   B|
+---+----+
|  a|null|
+---+----+


scala> df.filter(not($"B" <=> "d")).show
+---+----+
|  A|   B|
+---+----+
|  a|null|
+---+----+
```

Note in edit: the point of not being null safe by default is so to allow null as a result of a test. Is a missing value equal to "c"? We don't know. Is a missing value equal to another missing value? We don't know either.  But in a filter, null is false.