# What is the purpose of the alias method in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While learning Spark in Python, I'm having trouble understanding both the purpose of the `alias` method and its usage. The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) shows it being used to create copies of an existing `DataFrame` with new names, then join them together:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df_as1 = df.alias("df_as1")
>>> df_as2 = df.alias("df_as2")
>>> joined_df = df_as1.join(df_as2, col("df_as1.name") == col("df_as2.name"), 'inner')
>>> joined_df.select("df_as1.name", "df_as2.name", "df_as2.age").collect()
[Row(name=u'Bob', name=u'Bob', age=5), Row(name=u'Alice', name=u'Alice', age=2)]
```

My question has two parts:

1. What is the purpose of the `alias` input? It seems redundant to give the alias string `"df_as1"` when we are already assigning the new DataFrame to the variable `df_as1`. If we were to instead use `df_as1 = df.alias("new_df")`, where would `"new_df"` ever appear?
2. In general, when is the `alias` function useful? The example above feels a bit artificial, but from exploring tutorials and examples it seems to be used regularly -- I'm just not clear on what value it provides.

Edit: some of my original confusion came from the fact that both `DataFrame` and `Column` have `alias` methods. Nevertheless, I'm still curious about both of the above questions, with question 2 now applying to `Column.alias` as well.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730628/pyspark-join-and-then-column-select-is-showing-unexpected-output?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190828/spark-sql-performing-carthesian-join-instead-of-inner-join) question to understand the importance of alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The variable name is irrelevant and can be whatever you like it to   be. It's the alias what will be used in string column identifiers and    printouts.
2. I think that the main purpose of aliases is to achieve better brevity    and avoid possible confusion when having conflicting column names.    For example what was simply 'age' could be aliased to 'max_age' for    brevity after you searched for the biggest value in that column. Or    you could have a data frame for employees in a company joined with    itself and filter so that you have manager-subordinate pairs. It could be useful to use column names like "manager.name" in such context.