# Pyspark Join and then column select is showing unexpected output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am not sure if the long work is doing this to me but I am seeing some unexpected behavior in spark 2.2.0

I have created a toy example as below

```
toy_df = spark.createDataFrame([
['p1','a'],
['p1','b'],
['p1','c'],
['p2','a'],
['p2','b'],
['p2','d']],schema=['patient','drug'])
```

I create another dataframe

```
mdf = toy_df.filter(toy_df.drug == 'c')
```

as you know mdf would be

```
 mdf.show()
+-------+----+
|patient|drug|
+-------+----+
|     p1|   c|
+-------+----+
```

Now If I do this

```
toy_df.join(mdf,["patient"],"left").select(toy_df.patient.alias("P1"),toy_df.drug.alias('D1'),mdf.patient,mdf.drug).show()
```

Surprisingly I get

```
+---+---+-------+----+
| P1| D1|patient|drug|
+---+---+-------+----+
| p2|  a|     p2|   a|
| p2|  b|     p2|   b|
| p2|  d|     p2|   d|
| p1|  a|     p1|   a|
| p1|  b|     p1|   b|
| p1|  c|     p1|   c|
+---+---+-------+----+
```

but if I use

```
toy_df.join(mdf,["patient"],"left").show()
```

I do see the expected behavior

```
 patient|drug|drug|
+-------+----+----+
|     p2|   a|null|
|     p2|   b|null|
|     p2|   d|null|
|     p1|   a|   c|
|     p1|   b|   c|
|     p1|   c|   c|
+-------+----+----+
```

and if I use an alias expression on one of the dataframes I do get the expected behavior

```
toy_df.join(mdf.alias('D'),on=["patient"],how="left").select(toy_df.patient.alias("P1"),toy_df.drug.alias("D1"),'D.drug').show()

| P1| D1|drug|
+---+---+----+
| p2|  a|null|
| p2|  b|null|
| p2|  d|null|
| p1|  a|   c|
| p1|  b|   c|
| p1|  c|   c|
+---+---+----+
```

So my question is what is the best way to select columns after join and is this behavior normal

edit : as per user8371915 this is same as the question tagged as
[Spark SQL performing carthesian join instead of inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190828/spark-sql-performing-carthesian-join-instead-of-inner-join)

but my question works with two dataframe who have same lineage and performing the join when the show method is invoked but the select columns after join behaving differently .

Comment: Since the result of `df.col` or `df['col']` is a `Column` type which is not bound to the dataframe, I believe the result is expected. I'm wondering why aren't you getting `ambiguous column name` error while selecting in the erroneous case.

Comment: In general join between `DataFrames` sharing the same lineage can result in trivially true / false predicates. This case should be handled automatically, but it looks like things slipped through the cracks here. Honest advice - always use aliases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL performing carthesian join instead of inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190828/spark-sql-performing-carthesian-join-instead-of-inner-join)

Comment: @user8371915 does not look like the same question .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use aliases:

```
toy_df.alias("toy_df") \
    .join(mdf.alias("mdf"), ["patient"], "left") \
    .select(
        col("patient").alias("P1"),
        col("toy_df.drug").alias("D1"),
        col("patient").alias("patient"),
        col("mdf.drug").alias("drug")
    ) \
    .show()
```

The problem is that `mdf` is derived from `toy_df` so both `toy_df.drug` and `mdf.drug` refer to the same column. Therefore, when you pass those to `select`, Spark returns values from the same column as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate your findings and I wish I had an answer of why this happens. However, I was able to get your desired results by just changing the alias of the second (right) dataset. I changed mdf.drug to mdf.drugs

```
mdf = toy_df.filter(toy_df.drug == 'c').select(toy_df.patient,toy_df.drug.alias("drugs"))
```

so after the join..

```
toy_df.join(mdf,["patient"],"left").select(toy_df.patient.alias("P1"),toy_df.drug.alias('D1'),mdf.patient,mdf.drugs).show()
```

I got the expected behavior

```
| P1| D1|patient|drugs|
+---+---+-------+-----+
| p2|  a|     p2| null|
| p2|  b|     p2| null|
| p2|  d|     p2| null|
| p1|  a|     p1|    c|
| p1|  b|     p1|    c|
| p1|  c|     p1|    c|
+---+---+-------+-----+
```

I am going to do more research and see if I can expand to this initial answer